# Inserting 3D objects in the iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I would like to add few 3D objects in my iPhone application. My application is basically a eBook kind of a application & I would like to embed few 3D objects in 2 to 3 pages. I would like the users to rotate the 3D object and see various angles. Do I need to use any 3D applications such as Unity3D for such applications or I will be able to achieve this using just Objective C. Please help me..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at:

http://isgl3d.com/

as it's objective c based.

Answer (score 0):

[SIO2](http://sio2interactive.com/learningresource.php) is simple and free 3D engine.

Comment: thanks..more precise question is even if I have to have a one element of 3D object in my app, do I need to use some 3D engine to develop the complete app? or just the 3D part can be developed and embedded with the app?

Comment: Yes, if you have 3d object, you should add to project some 3d engine for correct rendering, displaying. Maybe, you will not use any function from 3d engine, but to present your model this engine must be included in the project.